# History in Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm doing my first steps with Clojure, but for some reason the up/down keys don't allow me to step through the command history in the REPL like in REPLs of other languages. Does the Clojure REPL use different keys to access the command history, or is this feature just not (yet) implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enhance the REPL to do this by using JLine, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Getting_Started#Enhancing_the_Environment).

Comment: I am running Ubuntu, JLine fixes history at the expense of breaking delete?

Answer (score 23):

If you are, by any chance, using a Unix-like environment you can use `rlwrap` to to achieve nice things like command line history and Ctrl-R for searching through it.

Just prepend your command which you use to start repl, e.g:

`rlwrap java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main`

Comment: this worked well, on os x. I just did 'brew install rlwrap' and was ready to go. Lein works great also.

Comment: the command above didn't work for me, but a simpler variant did:
     
     rlwrap lein repl

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk: The command above works even if you don't have lein installed, but assumes that you set the classpath (the `cp` parameter) to point correctly to the clojure jar - in this case in the same directory. If you use lein (which is actually the recommended way) you don't need to type `rlwrap` at all - it comes included with this functionality, try it out - just `lein repl`.

Comment: @GoranJovic Ah yeah you are right, `lein repl` just works already :)

Answer (score 8):

Or use Leiningen or Cake. Either of these are useful in general, and you'll be happy to learn to use them, but specifically they use readline or jline automatically where available.

Comment: + 2! `lein repl` is your friend

Comment: 'lein swank' is also your friend, then emacs will provide syntax highlighting, paredit and other goodies.

Answer (score 2):

Depends which REPL you use. Most good REPLs have this functionality and more.

If you're coming from Java as an Eclipse user, for example, you may want to use the embedded [nREPL](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) provided by the Counterclockwise plugin. I found this easier to use than configuring a separate dedicated Clojure environment.

Answer (score 1):

C-, M-x slime-repl-forward-input
C-, M-x slime-repl-backward-input
    Go to the next/previous history item.

http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Input-Navigation.html